# How to broadcast an intent that won't show my own app in the picker?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that sets up an intent filter on intent.action.send, mimeType text/plain, so that I can pick up share with intents (e.g. sharing a webpage from the browser). However, my app also broadcasts a similarly schemed intent to push things to the email client. The problem is now that when I launch this latter intent, my own app shows up in the picker. Is there a way to exclude my app from appearing there?

Answer (score 0):

Filter your own app out of the share intent list

Just query the package manager with the intent you want to send with queryIntentActivities and then just build the ui to include all other intents but not your own app.

Comment: As far as I can tell, from every post I can find online, the intent you specify for sending to email is intent.action.send with mimeType text/plain. Can you tell me how to get narrower than that..?